# list two possible coordinates of the third vertex so that the triangle has the area of 20 square units

Tags: geometry

I've been having a hard time with this problem.  I'm in advanced math at my school and I don't want to let the teacher down can anyone help me?  The problem is list two possible coordinates of the third vertex so that the triangle has the area of 20 square units.

The two given coordinates are $(1,-4)$ and $(6,-4)$

Comment: What are the coordinates of the first two vertices?

Comment: In addition to providing the coordinates of the first two vertices (without which we can't do a whole lot to help), what have you tried so far on this problem; what are your thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: the coordinates are (1,-4) and (6,-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use the formula that the area is half the base times the height.  The base is the distance between the two vertices.  Divide that into (what?) to get the altitude.  The third point has to be on one of the two lines parallel to the base and the altitude away.

Comment: Aren't there infinite possible answers?

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh:  yes there are.  Any points on the two lines I indicated would satisfy the requirement.